# Executing Actions within Actions for collection without creating new collection

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections, lambda

I have collection of objects where each object contains other collections of objects. All I want to modify my original collection of objects in a way, that no extra memory should be allocated. Everything should happen in memory.

I am looking for some templatized Action or Func so that with the mixture of declarative and functional approach, no new collection is formed and in memory my original collection is also modified.

Following is the hierarchy of collection

```
public class ConsignmentAddress
{
    public int ConsignmentAddressId { get; set; }
    public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int ConsignmentId { get; set; }


}
public class ConsignmentLine
{
    public int ConsignmentLineId { get; set; }
    public int PackagingId { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public int ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public int? PackagingAidId { get; set; }


}
public class PackagingAid
{
    public int PackagingAidId { get; set; }
    public int ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public int PackagingId { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}
public class Consignment
{
    public int ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public int ClientSubsidiaryId { get; set; }
    public int ForwarderId { get; set; }
    public int Sourcepaty { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PackagingAid> PackagingAids { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConsignmentLine> ConsignmentLines { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConsignmentAddress> ConsignmentAddresses { get; set; }

    public Consignment()
    {
        PackagingAids = new List<PackagingAid>();
        ConsignmentLines = new List<ConsignmentLine>();
        ConsignmentAddresses = new List<ConsignmentAddress>();
    }        
}
```

My intention is to write generic extension method which should operate on all kind of objects in the hierarchy I mentioned above.

```
public static class ConsignmentExtension
{
    public static T Set<T>(this T input, Action<T> updater)
    {
        updater(input);
        return input;
    }
}
```

Where as my client code is which is first getting list of 10000 of objects in list and just resetting few properties of ( consignment, consignmentaddresses for corresponding consignment, consignmentlines of corresponding consignment and packagingaid of corresponding consignment)

My written Foreach approach worked fine but i want templatized and efficient approach for the same collection.

```
consignments.ForEach(cons => 
        {
                                        cons.ConsignmentId = -1;
                                        cons.ConsignmentAddresses.ToList().ForEach(address => 
                                        {
                                            address.ConsignmentId = -1;
                                            address.ConsignmentAddressId = -1;
                                        });
                                        cons.ConsignmentLines.ToList().ForEach(line => 
                                        {
                                            line.ConsignmentId = -1;
                                            line.ConsignmentLineId = -1;
                                            line.PackagingAidId = -1;
                                        });
                                        cons.PackagingAids.ToList().ForEach(aid => 
                                        {
                                            aid.ConsignmentId = -1;
                                            aid.PackagingAidId = -1;
                                        });                                             
        });
```

But I am looking for something like declarative style.

```
var updatedConsignments = from consignment in consignments
                                  select consignment.Set<Consignment>(con =>
                                  {
                                      con.ConsignmentId = -1;
                                      con.ConsignmentAddresses.Set<dynamic>(address => { address.ConsignmentId = -1; address.ConsignmentAddressId = -1; });
                                      con.ConsignmentLines.Set<dynamic>(line => { line.PackagingAidId = -1; line.ConsignmentId = -1;line.ConsignmentLineId = -1; });
                                      con.PackagingAids.Set<dynamic>(aid => { aid.ConsignmentId = -1; aid.PackagingAidId = -1; });
                                  });
```

Is that possible somehow? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This could be written as

```
public static class ConsignmentExtension
{
   public static IEnumerable<dynamic> SetEach(this IEnumerable<dynamic> input, Action<dynamic> updater)
   {
       foreach (var item in input)
       {
           updater(item);
       }

       return input;
}
```

}

Usage:

```
           var addresses = new [] 
            {
                new ConsignmentAddress()
            };

            addresses.SetEach(a => a.ConsignmentId = -1);

            var packages = new []
            {
                new PackagingAid()
            };
            packages.SetEach(p => p.PackagingAidId = -1);
```